# Diagnostic plots for count regression

Tags: generalized-linear-model, residuals, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation, poisson-regression

What diagnostic plots (and perhaps formal tests) do you find most informative for regressions where the outcome is a count variable?

I'm especially interested in Poisson and negative binomial models, as well as zero-inflated and hurdle counterparts of each. Most of the sources I've found simply plot the residuals vs. fitted values without discussion of what these plots "should" look like.

Wisdom and references greatly appreciated. The back story on why I'm asking this, if it's relevant, is [my other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70397/enormous-ses-in-zero-inflated-negative-binomial-regression).

Related discussions:

- [Interpreting residual diagnostic plots for glm models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29271/interpreting-residual-diagnostic-plots-for-glm-models)
- [Assumptions of generalized linear models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49762/assumptions-of-generalized-linear-models)
- [GLMs - Diagnostics and Which Family](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44643/glms-diagnostics-and-which-family)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Here is what I usually like doing (for illustration I use the overdispersed and not very easily modelled quine data of pupil's days absent from school from `MASS`):

1. **Test and graph the original count data** by plotting observed frequencies and fitted frequencies (see chapter 2 in [Friendly](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1580256600)) which is supported by the `vcd` package in `R` in large parts. For example, with `goodfit` and a `rootogram`:

   ```r
   library(MASS)
   library(vcd)
   data(quine) 
   fit <- goodfit(quine$Days) 
   summary(fit) 
   rootogram(fit)
   ```

   or with **[Ord plots](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2343403)** which help in identifying which count data model is underlying (e.g., here the slope is positive and the intercept is positive which speaks for a negative binomial distribution):

   ```r
   Ord_plot(quine$Days)
   ```

   or with the **"XXXXXXness" plots** where XXXXX is the distribution of choice, say Poissoness plot (which speaks against Poisson, try also `type="nbinom"`):

   ```r
   distplot(quine$Days, type="poisson")
   ```
2. Inspect usual **goodness-of-fit measures** (such as likelihood ratio statistics vs. a null model or similar):

   ```r
   mod1 <- glm(Days~Age+Sex, data=quine, family="poisson")
   summary(mod1)
   anova(mod1, test="Chisq")
   ```
3. Check for **over / underdispersion** by looking at `residual deviance/df` or at a formal test statistic (e.g., [see this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66586/is-there-a-test-to-determine-whether-glm-overdispersion-is-significant/66593#66593)). Here we have clearly overdispersion:

   ```r
   library(AER)
   deviance(mod1)/mod1$df.residual
   dispersiontest(mod1)
   ```
4. Check for **influential and leverage points**, e.g., with the `influencePlot` in the `car` package. Of course here many points are highly influential because Poisson is a bad model:

   ```r
   library(car)
   influencePlot(mod1)
   ```
5. Check for **zero inflation** by fitting a count data model and its zeroinflated / hurdle counterpart and compare them (usually with AIC). Here a zero inflated model would fit better than the simple Poisson (again probably due to overdispersion):

   ```r
   library(pscl)
   mod2 <- zeroinfl(Days~Age+Sex, data=quine, dist="poisson")
   AIC(mod1, mod2)
   ```
6. **Plot the residuals** (raw, deviance or scaled) on the y-axis vs. the (log) predicted values (or the linear predictor) on the x-axis. Here we see some very large residuals and a substantial deviance of the deviance residuals from the normal (speaking against the Poisson; Edit: @FlorianHartig's answer suggests that normality of these residuals is not to be expected so this is not a conclusive clue):

   ```r
   res <- residuals(mod1, type="deviance")
   plot(log(predict(mod1)), res)
   abline(h=0, lty=2)
   qqnorm(res)
   qqline(res)
   ```
7. If interested, plot a **half normal probability plot** of residuals by plotting ordered absolute residuals vs. expected normal values [Atkinson (1981)](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/68/1/13.short). A special feature would be to simulate a reference ‘line’ and envelope with simulated / bootstrapped confidence intervals (not shown though):

   ```r
   library(faraway)
   halfnorm(residuals(mod1))
   ```
8. **Diagnostic plots** for log linear models for count data (see chapters 7.2 and 7.7 in Friendly's book). Plot predicted vs. observed values perhaps with some interval estimate (I did just for the age groups--here we see again that we are pretty far off with our estimates due to the overdispersion apart, perhaps, in group F3. The pink points are the point prediction $\pm$ one standard error):

   ```r
   plot(Days~Age, data=quine) 
   prs  <- predict(mod1, type="response", se.fit=TRUE)
   pris <- data.frame("pest"=prs[[1]], "lwr"=prs[[1]]-prs[[2]], "upr"=prs[[1]]+prs[[2]])
   points(pris$pest ~ quine$Age, col="red")
   points(pris$lwr  ~ quine$Age, col="pink", pch=19)
   points(pris$upr  ~ quine$Age, col="pink", pch=19)
   ```

This should give you much of the useful information about your analysis and most steps work for all standard count data distributions (e.g., Poisson, Negative Binomial, COM Poisson, Power Laws).

Comment: Great thorough answer! It was helpful to also run through these diagnostics with Poisson-simulated data to train my eye with what the plots should look like.

Comment: Should i have given more explanation to what the plots do or was it okay this way?

Comment: Interesting side note: I'm finding that the NB distribution rarely appears to fit simulated NB data based on the GOF test, rootogram, Ord plot, and NB-ness plot. The exception seems to be very "tame" NB data that is nearly symmetric -- high mu, high theta.

Comment: Hm, are your sure you use type="nbinomial" as argument? E.g. fm <- glm.nb(Days ~ ., data = quine); dummy <- rnegbin(fitted(fm), theta = 4.5) works fine.

Comment: @Momo, thanks -- I was doing something like x = rnegbin(n=1000, mu=10, theta=1); fit = goodfit(x, type="nbinomial"); summary(fit). Setting theta=4.5 does improve the fit, but it's still often p<0.05 and the rootogram can look pretty bad. Just so I understand the difference between our simulations: in yours, each value of dummy was simulated from a different mean parameter (a value in fitted(fm)), right? In mine, they all have mean 10.

Comment: @half-pass: Yes, you are right. It takes the predicted mean of each observation and draws one negative binomial random number. To get back to the first question: These are diagnostic plots so they are there to support a decision rather than making it. Personally, I'd only heuristically interpret p values in the displayed tests (after all, $H_0$ is that the model holds, so having large $n$ will have its effect). I'd rather just compare different plots/test stats and see what seems more appropriate.

Comment: ...in your example, with set.seed(1) the negative binomial gets better results than both poisson or binomial. Also read the caveat in ?goodfit regarding count data. The rootogram looks nice enough to me only the observations at count 17 and 19, 31 look to be a bit off. In the Ord plot, the slope is positive, so it should be an overdispersed count either a log series (what the negative intercept points to) or a negative binomial (the intercept is not too largely negative). The NBness plot is also pretty clearly in accordance with the data. So, I don't agree 100% with your side note.

Comment: Dear @Momo, I am including a diagnostic plot as in your #8 in a paper -- how would you like to be cited or acknowledged? I didn't see that exact idea in Friendly, and anyway the code is yours.

Comment: Dear @half-pass it's kind of you to ask but no need to cite anything. See also here, meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/at-what-point-do-i-have-to-reference-acknowledge-stackexchange-users/ The plot (while not particularly appealing) is pretty standard in my opinion. Perhaps for a publication you'd like to draw bars instead of points for the uncertainty intervals.

Answer (score 22):

For the approach of using standard diagnostic plots but wanting to know what they should look like, I like the paper:

> ```
>  Buja, A., Cook, D. Hofmann, H., Lawrence, M. Lee, E.-K., Swayne,
>  D.F and Wickham, H. (2009) Statistical Inference for exploratory
>  data analysis and model diagnostics Phil. Trans. R. Soc. A 2009
>  367, 4361-4383 doi: 10.1098/rsta.2009.0120
> ```

One of the approaches mentioned there is to create several simulated datasets where the assumptions of interest are true and create the diagnostic plots for these simulated datasets and also create the diagnostic plot for the real data.  put all these plots on the screen at the same time (randomly placing the one based on real data).  Now you have a visual reference of what the plots should look like and if the assumptions hold for the real data then that plot should look just like the others (if you cannot tell which is the real data, then the assumptions being tested are likely close enough to true), but if the real data plot looks clearly different from the other, then that means that at least one of the assumptions don't hold.  The `vis.test` function in the TeachingDemos package for R helps implement this as a test.

Comment: An example with the above data, for the record: mod1 <- glm(Days~Age+Sex, data=quine, family="poisson"); if(interactive()) {vis.test(residuals(mod1, type="response"), vt.qqnorm, nrow=5, ncol=5, npage=3)}

Answer (score 20):

This is an old question, but I thought it would be useful to add that my DHARMa R package (available from CRAN, see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html)) now provides standardized residuals for GLMs and GLMMs, based on a simulation approach similar to what is suggested by @GregSnow.

From the package description:

> The DHARMa package uses a simulation-based approach to create readily
>   interpretable scaled residuals from fitted generalized linear mixed
>   models. Currently supported are all 'merMod' classes from 'lme4'
>   ('lmerMod', 'glmerMod'), 'glm' (including 'negbin' from 'MASS', but
>   excluding quasi-distributions) and 'lm' model classes. Alternatively,
>   externally created simulations, e.g. posterior predictive simulations
>   from Bayesian software such as 'JAGS', 'STAN', or 'BUGS' can be
>   processed as well. The resulting residuals are standardized to values
>   between 0 and 1 and can be interpreted as intuitively as residuals
>   from a linear regression. The package also provides a number of plot
>   and test functions for typical model mispecification problem, such as
>   over/underdispersion, zero-inflation, and spatial / temporal
>   autocorrelation.

@Momo - you may want to update your recommendation 6, it is misleading. **Normality of deviance residuals is in general not expected under a Poisson**, as explained in the [DHARMa vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92394/checking-residuals-for-normality-in-generalised-linear-models); and **seing deviance residuals (or any other standard residuals) that differ from a straight line in a qqnorm plot is therefore in general no concern at all**. The DHARMa package provides a qq plot that is reliable for diagnosing deviations from Poisson or other GLM families. I have created an example that demonstrates the problem with the deviance residuals [here](https://github.com/florianhartig/DHARMa/blob/master/Code/Examples/DevianceResiduals.md).

Answer (score 5):

There is a function called `glm.diag.plots` in package `boot`, to generate diagnostic plots for GLMs. What it does:

> Makes plot of jackknife deviance residuals against linear predictor,
>   normal scores plots of standardized deviance residuals, plot of
>   approximate Cook statistics against leverage/(1-leverage), and case
>   plot of Cook statistic.

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely recommend the {[performance](https://github.com/easystats/performance)} package. It has a `check_model(mod1)` function that shows the relevant diagnostic plots.

```r
library(MASS)
data(quine) 
  
mod1 <- glm(Days~Age+Sex, data=quine, family="poisson")
summary(mod1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = Days ~ Age + Sex, family = "poisson", data = quine)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
#> -6.647  -2.964  -1.299   1.465  10.258  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)  2.63090    0.05693  46.215  < 2e-16 ***
#> AgeF1       -0.25232    0.06804  -3.708 0.000209 ***
#> AgeF2        0.35964    0.06083   5.913 3.37e-09 ***
#> AgeF3        0.29915    0.06412   4.665 3.08e-06 ***
#> SexM         0.10476    0.04181   2.506 0.012221 *  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 2073.5  on 145  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 1908.3  on 141  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 2506.8
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

performance::check_model(mod1)
#> Loading required namespace: qqplotr
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Warning: ggrepel: 138 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider
#> increasing max.overlaps
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>