# Statistical test for count data

Tags: r, biostatistics, count-data

I'm currently trying to figure out which statistical test to use for my count data, and I'm a little confused on how to go about it. The data that I'm working with consists of number of camera trap detections for five different species at three different heights over a period of one week. Camera location and orientation remained constant, so height should be the only variable. I'm trying to determine if there is a significant difference between the number of detections for each of the five species at the three different heights. There is one count of zero, as no detections where recorded at one height for a particular species. I know that chi square might be an option, but I was unsure if a generalised linear mixed model might be more appropriate. I will be using R to run the tests and I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Some kind of regression model could make sense here. What makes you think of a mixed effects model? I’m not sure I see a random effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diagnostic plots for count regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70558/diagnostic-plots-for-count-regression) That page has several examples of Poisson and negative binomial models for count data, and advice on how to judge the quality of the fit. As @Dave said, there doesn't seem to be a random effect here, so a standard generalized linear Poisson or negative binomial model should be OK.